# make requirejs ignore library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, materialize

I am loading an external dependency that work as an AMD module but it requires who knows how many sub libraries that are not on a path configured by my config.

Is there a way to tell requirejs to NOT load a library as a module and instead just let me include it as a normal script tag.

example:

library.js:

```
if (typeof define === "function) { // or how ever they do the optional define stuff
// do some amd stuff
} else {
// set it globally
}
```

normally requirejs will see this if loaded as a script tag and freak out about how it was read.  I want requirejs to just ignore it and let it be set globally so I do not have to worry about all the libraries it depends on.

Currently what I am doing is setting define to undefined before I call the script then set it back after I call the script.  That seemed to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a bundled version of the lib you are including. If the lib doesn't have bundled js file available, then you can create your own using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

`browserify some-library.js -o bundled-some-library.js`

As long as you have the dependencies installed at the time you bundle the lib, then it will give you a single file that you can then use as a script tag src.

Comment: does that work with multiple AMD dependencies?

Also the problem is when I use it as a script tag requirejs makes the file I am loading throw up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about multiple dependencies, but yes, bundling modules will allow them to work in a script tag